# R, plm, fitted values

Tags: r, plm

I try to use a GoF measure called MAPE mean absolute percentage error, I know there are some related answers that `a$model[[1]]-a$residuals` is the best way in the the plm package.
The problem is I use first differences and lagged variables, `length(a$model[[1]])` is 3327 and `length(a$residuals)` is 2845.
Any ideas how I could still use percentage error measures?

Comment: couldn't find a \ command to write a dollar sign, any help?

Comment: What's the question here? How best to calculate this in R? Seems off-topic if so.

Comment: There is some statistical background to it because the number of residuals in a first-differenced model is not equal to the number of (original) observations.

Answer (score 3):

For first-difference (and between) models, the model frame (what you get via `model_object$model`) is the original data and has more observations than the transformed data the first-differenced model is estimated on (you lose 1 observation per individual due to first-differencing). This is why the number of rows do not match the number of entries of the residual vector.

Use `pmodel.response()` to get the transformed (in this case first-differenced) response variable: `pmodel.response(a) - a$residuals`.

NB: For your use case, only use `pmodel.response()` for FD or between models, not for other model types.